# Undefined reference errors are coming when trying to compile a c++ project that uses SFML library

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sfml, undefined-reference

I am having some problem compiling a simple program in linux :-

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this program from the terminal (or from an IDE), these undefined reference errors are coming :-

```
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_action@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_new@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_receive_device@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_devnode@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_enable_receiving@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_new@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_get_fd@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_property_value@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_syspath@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_new_from_netlink@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype@LIBUDEV_183'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Edit:

to compile the program, I entered :-

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

after that, to link the sfml library to the program I entered this line :-

```
g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Comment: Can you show exactly what you entered in your terminal to compile it?

Comment: Have you tried with -ludev?

Comment: anyways I upgraded my os to ubuntu 14.04 and I got sfml 2.1 in software center which installed correctly. So the problem is solved.

Comment: I had a similar issue and had to simply upgrade g++ to 4.9.

Answer (score -2):

Link the files of lib folder properly.

Comment: Can you explain how to link the files properly with an example, if you don't mind? :)

Comment: explin your answer